# Memory leak in JNI

Tags: java, c++, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I developed a Cpp library with JNI. The CPP library has functions to which I pass string Array and nums Array from java. Unfortunately, when I run entire program, memory usage of process is increasing and finally getting killed. I convert the string Array, nums Array from Java to C format using below functions. I also return a string from the function back to Java.

I want to know whether there's memory in leak in the following functions

```
myVector<string> getCStringFromJavaString(jobjectArray msgWordsStrArray,JNIEnv *env){
  int stringCount = env->GetArrayLength(msgWordsStrArray);
  myVector<string> msgWordsArray;

  for (int i=0; i<stringCount; i++) {
    jstring orig = (jstring) (env->GetObjectArrayElement(msgWordsStrArray, i));
    const char *rawString = env->GetStringUTFChars(orig, 0);
    msgWordsArray.push_back(rawString);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(orig,rawString);
  }

  return msgWordsArray;

}

myVector<myDouble> getMyDoubleFromJavaDouble(jdoubleArray numsArray,JNIEnv *env){
  int numsCount = env->GetArrayLength(numsArray);
  myVector<myDouble> N;
  double *numsArrayCStyle = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(numsArray,0);

  for(int i = 0;i < numsCount; i++ ){
    double orig = numsArrayCStyle[i];
    myDouble origMyDouble(orig);
    N.push_back(origMyDouble); 
  }
  env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(numsArray, numsArrayCStyle, JNI_ABORT);

  return N;
}

jstring getJStringFromCString(string cstring,JNIEnv *env){
   return env->NewStringUTF(cstring.c_str());
}
```

PS: myDouble,myVector are classes that mimic the vector,double in cpp. There's no memory leak in them

Comment: Try using a tool that can detect memory leaks, such as Valgrind or AddressSanitizer. As an aside, the loop in `getCStringFromJavaString` keeps creating local references (`orig`) which it doesn't delete.

Comment: Are you sure about your vector and double classes? Do they have valid copy constructors, for example? And why do you have a vector class at all when `std::vector` already exists? Try it with `std::vector<>`. And can you test these methods one at a time to see if it's only one of them leaking?

Comment: @Michael I am releasing the orig using ReleaseStringUTFChars, will it not free orig?
Also, I am not sure on how to use valgrind with JNI. I ran valgrind by using other parts of code written in cpp and there were no memory leaks

Comment: No, that frees the `rawString` you have obtained from `orig` with `GetStringUTFChars`.

Comment: @Michael Will the references not get destroyed after each loop?

Comment: No, because this is a reference to a Java object, not a C++ reference. You created the reference by calling `GetObjectArrayElement`, and C++ has no idea about that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out. Does the object stay alive till JNI function call is returned to Java?
Also, in env->NewStringUTF(cstring.c_str()) will there not be any local reference?

Comment: Pretty much every JNI function that returns a `jobject` or `jclass` will result in a new local reference being created. And yes, if your call stack originated in Java and you return back to Java, the local reference table will be cleared for you. It is not clear from the code you've shown us whether that will ever happen.